# How to use bcp for columns that are Identity?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I want to restore my table with BCP by code in the below.

```
BCP framework.att.attendance in "D:\test\mhd.txt" -T -c
```

But the column (id) is identity in this table.

When data is restored with BCP I want id columns to be unchanged.

In other words, if the id of the first row is '7' before BCP, I want to import data and the id of the first row will be still be '7'.

What should I do?

Comment: If you google for `bcp identity insert` you'll find a lot of results, starting with the official docs: [Keep identity values when bulk importing data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-identity-values-when-bulk-importing-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). You can use the `-E` option with `bcp` or `KEEPIDENTITY` with `BULK INSERT`. There are many similar questions in SO too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos tanx
i want use bcp from client system -i cant remote to that.hjow can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**BCP IMPORT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#f)

**-E**

> - -E Specifies that identity value or values in the imported data file are to be used for the identity column.
> - If -E is not given, the identity values for this column in the data file being imported are ignored.